# About Relative keys

Tags: theory, chord-theory

C Major key's Sub Dominant relative key is F.
But instead, could Fm key also be a Relative key ?

So if that works..

From c minor key, could F Major be a relative key also ?

Comment: As far as I know, the only *relatives* are a major and its relative minor. So called due to both sharing the same key sig. True, F is the subdominant of C, but it would appear this question is asked on false premises. **Parallel keys** are something that may be what's meant here. But there's always going to be that 'lost in the translation', as in some languages, parallel means relative. If that's the case, I suggest we stick with the English meaning, meaning we're all on the same hymn sheet.

Comment: http://learnmusictheory.net/PDFs/pdffiles/03-03-TypesOfKeyRelationships.pdf Check this out.

Answer (score 2):

In common terminology, keys may be 'related' in various ways and to various degrees.  C major has a close 'relationship' with C minor.  It's pretty close to F major, G major.  It's hardly 'related' at all to F# major (though I could confuse you  with the 'b5 substitution' :-)

But in music terminology, 'Relative' has a specific meaning.  It refers to the pair of major/minor keys that have the same key signature.  C major and A minor, D major and B minor etc.  Keep the word 'relative' for that.

(As @Tim commented, there may be translation issues here.  But, in any language, I think there will be the concept of relative major/minor as a special type of relationship, with a special name.)

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with translation here. Other answers address the relative keys of, e.g., C major and A minor, but I wonder if you're asking about **closely related keys**.

Traditionally, *closely related keys* are defined as keys whose key signatures differ by only one accidental. The keys closely related to C major are thus D minor (one flat difference), E minor (one sharp difference), F major (one flat difference), G major (one sharp difference), and A minor (no difference).

By this metric, F major and C major are closely related keys.

F minor, having four flats in the key signature, is thus *not* closely related to C major. However, there is a clear relationship between the two that allows one to smoothly move between them: C major is the dominant of F minor. So even if the two keys aren't "closely related," it's still pretty easy to switch between them smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

in German I would say: jein! What means Yes and No.

But actually the answer is: no!

**Relative keys have the same signature**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_key

but you are speaking about

**Parallel minor and parallel major keys that have the same tonic**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_key

So fm as the minor subdominant in C is borrowed from the minor parallel of cm

and F as the major subdominant in cm is borrowed from the major parallel of C

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_chord